# Is there an option in ffmpeg to make a 50 fps video to 25 fps with double duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Have a 5 sec video with 50 fps 
Want to convert it to a 25 fps video with 10 seconds and everything slowed down even the audio 
Is it possible using ffmpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf setpts=PTS*2 -r 25 -af atempo=0.5 output.mp4
```